# What is Old GC and Young GC in JAVA

Tags: java, garbage-collection

What is the key difference in Old and Young Garbage Collector? How JVM differentiate which GC is to be used.

Comment: Sorry  I am new to StackOverflow. I am just curious about GC and JVM internal working  so asked this question

Comment: Can some buddy please mark this duplicate and close this question

Comment: Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)